# How to set env variable so Karma can run Opera broswer

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, opera, karma-runner

I'm trying to set up Karma to run tests on Opera but it's giving me this error:

```
ERROR[launcher]: Cannot start Opera
Can not find the binary C:\Program Files\Opera\opera.exe
Please set the env variable OPERA_BIN
```

I don't really know anything about setting env variables so I did a little research and tried these in the cmd but to no avail:

```
C:\>set OPERA_BIN = C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\launcher.exe
```

...nothing happens..

```
C:\>setx OPERA_BIN = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\launcher.exe
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s)
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
set "OPERA_BIN=C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\launcher.exe"
```

Aditional spaces are stored both in the variable name and in the variable value.

Comment: Thanks this seemed to work in the cmd but for some reason karma still couldn't find the file. I ended up just moving the opera.exe file to C:\Program Files\Opera\ and karma could find it then. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Moving Opera.exe just means you will not run the updated version. Launcher.exe ensures the latest version is launched.  Did you try changing the directory to the Opera directory before starting launcher.exe ?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. When I get chance I'll try and make sure karma is pointed to launcher.exe rather than opera.exe.